# Can't use file_get_contents on https://api.facebook.com

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get some information using `https://api.facebook.com`

The following works just fine: (notice graph.facebook.com)

```
$q = "https://graph.facebook.com/$params".$sep."access_token=$access_token";
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($q),true);
```

But

```
$q = "https://api.facebook.com/$params".$sep."access_token=$access_token";
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($q),true);
```

Just does not work. I've tried curl, but I keep getting **Method Not Implemented**

Following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$url = "https://api.facebook.com/$params".$sep."access_token=$access_token";
echo $url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

echo curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_errno($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't require POST, does it?

Comment: Also, what is in `$params` and what is in `$sep`?

Comment: I've tried POST with the same error. $params and $sep are simply variables I use in this class. Never mind them, the $url is correct. I get the result I am looking for when going directly to that url. I just can't get the result in a variabel.

Comment: I would crack out Wireshark and look at the difference between the two requests, and try and mimic the successful one from PHP.

Comment: Is you php compiled with https support?

Comment: Well, the problem is that when the two requests are identical, I still get a error saying bad headers. Seems to me like api.facebook is running another system than graph.facebook

Comment: Meaning what @DmitriSnytkine ?

Comment: Without https support the file_get_contents() will fail to fetch from https url.

Comment: But it works when the url is graph.facebook. Only api.facebook gives me this error. And why does not my curl work then? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a silly mistake. I post the working example:

The call:

```
$status = $fb->api("method/fql.query?query=".urlencode("SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = $ID")."",$access_token);
```

The class:

```
class fb 
{
    public function api($params, $access_token) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $q = "https://api.facebook.com/$params?format=json-strings&access_token=$access_token";
            $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($q),true);

            if ($response->error->message != null) 
                throw new Exception($response->error->message);
            else
                return $response;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            return ("<b>Error:</b> " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

For everyone who don't want to use the facebook php sdk.

Comment: Why would someone not use (or extend) the official SDK?

Comment: This is much more lightweighted

Comment: Well, from just seeing ur code...you are retuning an array in `$response` (since you are using `,true`) but accessing it as object, which *I suppose* won't work! ;)

Comment: That is correct, I just foreach the `$status` variabel afterwards.